# How to join 3 tables in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm using mysql and php for fetching data.

These are my 3 tables.

1. sales `uid`=>primary `fname`(varchar)
2. meeting_details `uid`=>foreign/`date_time`(varchar)
3. travels `uid`=>foreign/`date_of_travel`(varchar)

I have a bootstrap datepicker. With the help of this I want to fetch
data of particular `fname` from `sales` table and fetch records from
`meeting_details` and `travels`.

If I select `fname` from dropdown then there should be fetch 2 tables of
particular user.

I want to create a join query for this.

Comment: Do you want to search for a sales person by name and date? If you want it to filter by date as well, do you need future meetings or past meetings?

Comment: @Samir i want to filter all meetings and all travelling info of particular sales person by selected date

Comment: @Styphon bro i tried this query but where condition is not working i guess. i got empty data    select travel_allwnce.mode_of_transport,sales.fname,sales.uid, ge,travel_allwnce.date_of_travel, meeting_details.brief_of_meeting,meeting_details.date_time,meeting_details.notes FROM travel_allwnce INNER JOIN meeting_details ON meeting_details.uid=travel_allwnce.uid INNER JOIN sales ON sales.uid=meeting_details.uid where sales.fname='$_POST[sales_name]' AND travel_allwnce.date_of_travel='$_REQUEST[startdate]' OR travel_allwnce.date_of_travel='$_REQUEST[enddate]'